# I got: IndexError: list index out of range, but I don't know why and it doesne't apper to affect the output

Tags: python, python-3.x, index-error

I was making a program to make an average of differences of numbers from an external .txt file. I wrote this and suddenly I get an index error. I think I know the meaning of this, the index doesn't exist. I don't know where the mistake is...

Also, the error comes out weird and is interrupted with other outputs (prints) and I have no clue why that is happening...

The list is here:

```
111
222
333
444
555
666
777
888
999
```

code:

```
file = open("list", "r")
lst = file.read().split("\n")

index = 0

for i in lst:
    num1 = lst[index]

    index += 1

    num2 = lst[index]

    print("NUM1:" + str(num1))
    print("NUM2:" + str(num2))

    dif = int(num2) - int(num1)

    print(dif)
```

The output doesn't look like there are any effects of the error...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
NUM1:111  
  File "FILE_LOCATION", line 11, in <module>  
NUM2:222  
    num2 = lst[index]  
111  
IndexError: list index out of range  
NUM1:222  
NUM2:333  
111  
NUM1:333  
NUM2:444  
111  
NUM1:444  
NUM2:555  
111  
NUM1:555  
NUM2:666  
111  
NUM1:666  
NUM2:777  
111  
NUM1:777  
NUM2:888  
111  
NUM1:888  
NUM2:999  
111  

Process finished with exit code 1
```

One more thing: the error is unpredictable and always appears in different places. Sometimes fully on the beginning, sometimes on the end, and sometimes throughout the output.

Comment: You get the error on the last iteration, because (surprise!) `index` is now 1 more than the largest allowed. Read about the `range` function.

Comment: What you show is not what I get when I run your code with your data file. The error comes *after* the rest of the printout. It also looks different than what you show. Perhaps your execution environment changes the order of the printing--what is your environment? Given that, do you still not understand the cause of the error?

Comment: Also, I copy pasted your code and text file, and running it actually yields => `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`. The code and text file provided does not seem to be giving the provided exception.

Comment: @idjaw: That `invalid literal` error happens if the file ends with a new-line character at the end of the `999` line. If there is no new-line character, the resulting error is indeed a `list index out of range` error.

Comment: @RoryDaulton My editor adds newlines on auto-save....that explains it. Doh! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For every element, you check difference between current and next element. However, the last element doesn't have *next* element, hence the error.

The reason you see the error before the output is probably due to the fact the output goes to the *standard output* and the error goes to the *standard error*, which are two different streams and they get flushed simultaneously when your application crashes.

The output seems not to be affected as you should stop at the last element, but you don't, so the program crashes after everything is printed.

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = []
for line in x.readlines():
    line = line.replace("\n","")
    list1.append(line)
for i in range(len(list1)):
    if i+1<len(list1):
        s1 = int(list1[i])
        s2 = int(list1[i+1])
        print(f"Num1->{s1}")
        print(f"Num2->{s2}")
        dif = s2-s1
        print(dif)
    else:
        print("List is completed")
```

The error is because of index Error as you have increased index to +1 in the above sample code and that index is not there in list type->lst. That's Why you got this error. Try This code will work for you